# Let $X = -10Y + 10$. Let $r_1$ be the correlation between $X$ and $Z$ and $r_2$ be the correlation between $Y$ and $Z$.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

Let $X = -10Y + 10$. Let $r_1$ be the correlation between $X$ and $Z$ and $r_2$ be the correlation between $Y$ and $Z$. Then, which of the following is the best answer?

1. $r_1 = r_2$.
2. $r_1 = 10r_2$
3. $r_1 = -10r_2$
4. $r_1 = -r_2$.
5. None of the above is correct.

I think Choice No.3 is the best answer because of the coef. of $Y$ is also $-10$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\Corr}{\operatorname{Corr}}\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
Using the known properties of covariance gives
\begin{align*}
\Corr(X,Z) &=\frac{\Cov(X,Z)}{\sqrt{\Var(X)\Var(Z)}}\\
&=\frac{\Cov(-10Y+10,Z)}{\sqrt{\Var(-10Y+10)\Var(z)}}\\
&=\frac{-10\Cov(Y,Z)}{\sqrt{100\Var(Y)\Var(Z)}}\\
&=\frac{-10\Cov(Y,Z)}{10\sqrt{\Var(Y)\Var(Z)}}\\
&=-\Corr(Y,Z).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$r_1 = -r_2,$$
which is option 4.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, compute. We have 
$$\text{Cov}(X,Z)=\text{Cov}(-10Y+10,Z)=-10\text{Cov}(Y,Z).$$
Also, $\text{Var}(X)=100\text{Var}(Y)$.
It follows that
$$\rho(X,Z)=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Z)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Z}=\frac{-10\text{Cov}(Y,Z)}{10\sigma_Y\sigma_Z},$$
and therefore $r_1=-r_2$.

Informally, scaling by some positive factor does not change the degree of linear relationship. Neither does a shift. Correlation does not depend on the scale of measurement.